# combining 3 indicators into a strategy

Tags: combinations, volume, moving-average

I want to combine 3 indicators (**MACD**, **EMA**, and **VOLUME**) to build a strategy where to get notified (`overlay=true`, with character) if the candle is over 7 days **EMA** and the **VOLUME** is higher than the previous 4 days and the **MACD** is in a positive direction.

```
strategy('MACD') 
    [macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)  
    ema7 = ema(close, 7) 
    buy = close > ema7 
    vol = volume 
    vol1 = volume[1] 
    vol2 = volume[2] 
    vol3 = volume[3] 
    buycon = buy and macdLine >= signalLine and vol > vol1 and vol > vol2 and vol > vol3 
    stopcon = close < ema7 
    start = timestamp(2019,1,1,0,0) 
    if time >= start     
        strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, 1000, when = buycon)     
        strategy.close("buy", when = stopcon)
```

Please help

Comment: You did not mention which software/language you are using. Please edit your post. Also, you first need to show that you have tried to solve the problem on your own. So what have you tried? And what problems did you encounter with your solution?

Comment: I am using TraidingView

Comment: You mean TradingView? Nice you tell us. So what have you tried? And what problems did you encounter with your solution?

Comment: ```strategy('MACD')
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

ema7 = ema(close, 7)
buy = close > ema7
vol = volume
vol1 = volume[1]
vol2 = volume[2]
vol3 = volume[3]
buycon = buy and macdLine >= signalLine and vol > vol1 and vol > vol2 and vol > vol3
stopcon = close < ema7
start = timestamp(2019,1,1,0,0)
if time >= start
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, 1000, when = buycon)
    strategy.close("buy", when = stopcon) ```

the problem is that it will conceder buying in the next day and not in the same day (once the volume is higher than previous days)